# saving xml output to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xml-serialization

In my project I need to read a csv file and convert it into xml and save the xml to database table. I want to save the xml Output directly to database without saving to a file.
I was able to convert csv to xml, but I am not sure how to save it(without saving to a file) 
database directly. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code

```
   var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\test.csv");

            var xml = new XElement("TopElement",
               lines.Select(line => new XElement("Item",
                line.Split(';')
                .Select((column, index) => new XElement("Column" + index, column)))));

           // XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(xml.ToString());


            //xml.Save(@"C:\xmloutput.xml);  // dont want to save to file.
```

Comment: What kind of database are you using?  You may want to do some research on ADO.NET

Comment: use a memorystream? and a binary field in your database. [example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tolong/archive/2007/11/15/read-write-xml-in-memory-stream.aspx)

Comment: Why not save the file as binary to databse why do you think it better the other way it a lot faster to save the file directly unless, you need to extract the data from, it

Comment: Why from excel file to xml and then to database? Why not directly to database?

Comment: You have the XML you want in the xml variable. Can't you just insert that into the database directly?

Comment: One more question: do you already the database created (the structre, like columns)? If so, simply go thorugh the lines of csv file, delimit row to get the columns and do an Indert query on each row!

Comment: I want to insert the entire data into one single row , In for later use, In such case above solutions doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have column of type "XMl" in database in case you are using SQL Server?

You can check [Save XML directly to Database with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991810/save-xml-directly-to-database-with-c-sharp)

Comment: I want to insert the entire data into one single row , In for later use, In such case above solutions doesn't work

Comment: Your solution is right. I was able to insert xml into table like any other data. Thanks for help

Comment: @Henry if the solution is correct then please UP vote as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining XML in SQL Server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510480(SQL.105).aspx

C# sample (converting XML to string):
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/d1666d13-dea3-4ce8-a818-6b852a63de4f/

Answer (score 0):

Implementing XML in SQL Server:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887(SQL.105).aspx

Other links:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1316853.aspx/1

Comment: I want to insert the entire data into one single row , In for later use, In such case above solutions doesn't work

Comment: You can make the whole xml as string or serialize and save it in single row. That is one of resolutions provided above.