# How to save XML(writer) in DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, xml, database, xmlwriter

I'm writing a program where the user is doing some stuff and can save then the XML to his hard drive by using SaveFileDialog().

The current code of creating the XML-file is this (snippet which should work by everyone):

```
SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(filename))
{
    try
    {
        writer.WriteStartDocument();

        writer.WriteStartElement("Questionnaire");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "noNamespaceSchemaLocation", null, "D:\\Schema.xsd");

        writer.WriteStartElement("Title");
        writer.WriteString("test");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteStartElement("Number");
        writer.WriteString("1");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
}
```

Now I also want to save the XML in my database. Either by using the column type `xml` in my table (I don't know how or what to save into this column) or by saving the full XML Code in a column of type `nvarchar`, which I actually would like to do.

How can I save the XML-file, which was created by a `XmlWriter` to my database (column of type `xml` or `string` which includes the xml)? By saying "which includes the xml" do I mean the full xml code, like

```
<Title>
    MyTitle
</Title>
```

Comment: You have an extra `writer.WriteEndElement();` line in your code.

Comment: Refer this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991810/save-xml-directly-to-database-with-c-sharp


it will be helpful for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following constructor:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
{ 
    // rest of your code above
    SaveToDb(sb.ToString());
}
```

And the `SaveToDb` method (validation and exception handling omitted):

```
private static void SaveToDb(string xml)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn))
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT MyXmlTable VALUES (@XML)",
        connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("XML", SqlDbType.Xml, xml.Length).Value = xml;
        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: _INSERT dbo.XML_Files (field2, field3) VALUES (@Number,@XML)_

Comment: Yeah nevermind, just saw that my column ID in my table wasn't auto_increment, that's why the error 'Column missing' popped up. Anyway, it's working perfectly, thanks :)